# When training deep learning model which is better, training with sampled data Vs. training on shorter epoch

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow, mathematics

I am running multiple hyperparameter optimization trials therefore trying to find a way to reduce time consumption. Two ways that I could think of are

1. search hyperparameter on subset of data.
2. search hyperparameter on shorter epoch on full data (shuffling on each epoch).

My take on this is
#1 will be beneficial if there are redundant data and subset of data represents population well. But if full data is already complex thus not easily represented by subset #2,#1 would be similar since total training batch would be similar.

Does anyone have answer to this with possible reference that proves its statement with mathematical rigor?